# How to access files and folders for uwp app on a mobile device

Tags: mobile, uwp

How can app files be accessed for uwp apps on a mobile device. This tutorial, https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/06/08/using-the-app-file-explorer-to-see-your-app-data/, explains using App File explorer. I follow the steps, enabling device portal and device discovery. With the IP address of the phone I can't connect to the phone from Google Chrome because of security. Microsoft edge allows me to connect with the pin after a warning about the security certificate  but the phone does not show a new pairing , and the device portal only has a few of the options from the tutorial, not File Explorer (https://i.stack.imgur.com/st5Sb.jpg).

Connecting by usb does not show app folders (https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqI9C.jpg)

Thank you.

Comment: What's the version of your mobile os? Have you upgraded to 14393?

Comment: I upgraded and can now access File explorer with Edge. But not by usb, is that normal?

Comment: please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your Mobile OS version and upgrade to the latest RTM

And you can also use **Device Portal core [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-api-core#app-file-explorer)**

For example:

Get known folders - Obtain a list of accessible top-level folders.

```
Method | Request URI
-------|------------
GET    | /api/filesystem/apps/knownfolders
```

> I upgraded and can now access File explorer with Edge. But not by usb, is that normal?

Please follow this guidance to [Set up device portal on Windows Phone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-mobile)